# Where do I add a class in this Rails collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm having trouble adding a class to this collection_select:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Choose a category'}, {:required => true} %>
```

I've tried this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Choose a category'}, {:required => true}, {:class => "form_inputs"} %>
```

As well as this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category"}, {required: true}, {class: "form_inputs"} %>
```

But neither seem to work. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this 
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Choose a category'}, :class => "form_inputs" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...tested.

```
<%= f.collection_select 'category_id', Category.all, 'id', 'name', {prompt: "Choose a category"}, class: "form_inputs", required:true %>
```